# How to use an Sqlite database for android apps on a closed network

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am currently developing an Android application which should be running on different devices in the same LAN. 
In this project I need to save some information from the different devices in a database.
I thought about having one of the devices to use the database and then the other devices could fetch/save data there. But that would be bad if that particular device crashes..
Also thought about having the same database on each of the devices and them make them synchronize every once in a while.

Well I'm really uncertain on what the best solution would be or if I should do something comletely different.. 
So, what would be the most appropriate way to set this database up? And is sqlite the best solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: central server with some db(mssql, mysql, sqlite, whatever) with some REST endpoint in the same LAN as devices ... on devices instead of using local sqlite db you are should use the endpoint (of course you could do some caching or even synchronization - depends on your skill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Syncing data between all phones when all of them have SqlLite db will quickly lead to very complex programming or easily get out of sync.
- To use a phone as a server seems flaky, although it's probably doable.
- In your case I would use a database in some sort of backend server on the LAN, from which the clients regularly pull data.

Just a side note:

. [With Parse](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) you store data in the cloud and it supports push. So whenever one device makes a change, you can push it to the other devices. But ok, that would of course only work if you have internet access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer VonSchnauzer. I ended up implementing the database on the server device (a tablet), maybe not the most appropriate solution generally, but in my case this will do just fine.

Comment: Unusual but interesting!